# fetch size of Kernel Opencl

Tags: opencl

I have two questions about memory fetch size of a OpenCL kernel.
In the kernel, I just put a for-loop statement and a printf statement inside the for-loop.
Currently, I am passing two arguments, a float array and a integer number that decides a number of looping of the for-loop. 
However, when I passed 0 for the number of looping (In other word, I made the kernel doing nothing), the kernel fetched 0.3125 kilobytes.
Why does the kernel fetch that amount of memory?

My another question is 
when there is a cache miss, occurred, why dose the kernel fetches memory less than a size of cache line?

Thanks!

Edit
Here is my kernel

```
__kernel void sequence(__global float *input, const unsigned int N) {             
  size_t id = get_global_id(0);
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        printf("Val: %f \n", input[i]);     
  }

}
```

Comment: Can we access to your kernel?

Comment: Just guessing, maybe the kernel code size itself is 320bytes (0.3125*1024=320B). Or you are running 40  work items, and each of them gets a global pointer and a constant value (4+4=8bytes), even though they are not used at all.